# Excel: Array formula which returns vector {1;2;3;...;n} of given lenght (n)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm creating a complex array formula and want to get rid of dependency on area which represent vector `{1;2;3;...;n}` where `n` is same number as row number in other area used in the formula.

Basically I have some (long and complex) Array Formula (`AF`) with links to whole table columns`A` and `B` and want to get rid of link to the column A.

If there is no possible change of row count in the table, link to row `A` could be replaced with `{1;2;3;4}` (for 4 rows in the table). BUT row count is changing time by time.

```
+---+-----+--------------+
| A |  B  |      C       |
+---+-----+--------------+
| 1 | 105 | =AF([A],[B]) |
| 2 |  55 | =AF([A],[B]) |
| 3 |  80 | =AF([A],[B]) |
| 4 |  11 | =AF([A],[B]) |
+---+-----+--------------+
```

Are you able to construct this formula with only input = row B (without using any side table)?

Many thanks!

PS: In current versions of Excel is function `SEQUENCE` availible, but not in 2013 which I have and kindly asking for your help with.

Comment: can you just use the row() function? =row(a1:a4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, it was so simple… I'm embarrassed. I (wrongly) assumed that `ROW` is unable to return vector. But it can.

### Formula may looks like:

- This solution reffers column B (data range) only:
  `{=ROW([B])-ROW(INDEX([B]),1))+1}`
- Or mole elegant (using table header as refference):
  `{=ROW([B])-ROW(TableName[#Headers])}`
  Where `TableName` is name of the table.
- Or without named ranges nor tables:
  `{=ROW($B$2:$B$#)-ROW($B$1)}`
  Where `A#` is last cell with data in row `B`
- Or super simple example (there is no table and data starts in `B1`):
  `{=ROW($B$1:$B$#)}`
  Where A# is last cell with data in row `B`

PS: I don't have English version of Excel, so terms translantion could be messy. Feel free to correct me.